# Mysql indexing for the sql query below

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a query like the one below

```
SELECT
                t1.categoryId as level1Id, t2.categoryId as level2Id, t3.categoryId as level3Id, t4.categoryId as level4Id, t5.categoryId as level5Id, t6.categoryId as level6Id, t7.categoryId as level7Id
                FROM `productCategories` as t1
                LEFT JOIN productCategories as t2 ON t1.categoryId = t2.parentcategoryId
                LEFT JOIN productCategories as t3 ON t2.categoryId = t3.parentcategoryId
                LEFT JOIN productCategories as t4 ON t3.categoryId = t4.parentcategoryId
                LEFT JOIN productCategories as t5 ON t4.categoryId = t5.parentcategoryId
                LEFT JOIN productCategories as t6 ON t5.categoryId = t6.parentcategoryId
                LEFT JOIN productCategories as t7 ON t6.categoryId = t7.parentcategoryId
                WHERE t1.categoryId IN ('" . $categories . "')
```

productCategories have about 15000 rows & 2020 unique parent ids.  Once I get all the unique category ids in an array, I start a new query to search the products with the matching category ids.  So things get a little slow at that point.  Any advice on how to improve with this query or create indexes?

Comment: Do you have an index on parentcategoryId ?

Comment: In the future you should rather post questions like this on 
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i have an index on parentcategoryid, yes

Comment: Then it should be fairly quick for the amount of data it is processing. Can you do an EXPLAIN on the query and post the results of it?

Comment: seems to be ok now, thanks everyone above.